# Logging to Google Cloud Logging from log4net

Tags: asp.net, windows, log4net, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-logging

I have an asp.net web application that emit logs via log4net. I need to get the log messages over to [Google Cloud Logging](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/). What is the best way to do this?

Based on [fluentd documentation](http://docs.fluentd.org/articles/windows) and [Google Cloud documentation](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/installation), the best I can come up with now is:

1. On the Windows machine where the web app is runnning, have log4net log to local files.
2. On the same machine, run [nxlog](http://nxlog.org/) and have it ship the log files to a Linux machine.
3. Have google-fluentd, running on the Linux machine, transmit the logs to Google Cloud Logging API.

Answer (score 2):

An easier solution path than the one I started with is to use the [Google Cloud Logging API Client Library for .NET](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/apis/logging/v1beta3).

Currently at v1 beta 3 it's based on the [Google Cloud Logging API](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/api/ref/rest/) and has a [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Logging.v1beta3/).